# Is there a way to bridge differences between given code and implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In a snake game, the game model doesen't support the implementation that I would like to use.

I'm taking part in a friendly competition of who can write the best AI for a snake game. The game model is a given, we cannot change anything in it. I would like to implement an A* pathfinding AI. The problem is that the coordinates in the games are written in a way that they don't support this solution. The nodes that i would like to use look like the example below.

```
public final class Coordinate {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    }

public class Node {

    private int aStarValueG;
    private int aStarValueF;
    private int aStarValueH;
    private int coordinateX;
    private int coordinateY;
    private boolean isBlocked;
    private Node parent;
    }
```

I am looking for a way to brigde the differences between the 2 classes. I would like my AI to communicate with the coordinates through the nodes, and vice-verse. I'm familiar with design patterns, and I feel like they are the solution to this problem, but I don't know how.
I'm also open to any other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Just bing the x with coordinateX and sam with Y no ?

Comment: The snake board is using the methods of the coordinates, so I am looking for a solution to apply any change of the coordinates to the nodes.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an [Adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter).

Comment: [Decorator design pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/decorator-design-pattern-in-java) could work too

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, I think you mean you want Node and Coordinate instances to both be able to be used? Well, use template method (design pattern), by having some sort of interface both classes implement, and your algorithm should use methods from that interface. If your algorithm can't support this (due to runtime changes etc), you may want to look into some other variability patterns: Strategy, State, Bridge etc.